# Error 1064 (42000) you have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Artist 
(ArtistName varchar(20), BirthDate date, DeathDate date, ADescription text(100), CONSTRAINT ArtistKey PRIMARY KEY (ArtistName varchar(20) NOT NULL);
```

It says I need to

> check the right syntax to use near varchar (20) NOT NULL in line 2.

How do I fix this??

Comment: text(100) is not correct for SQL Server ...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Artist 
(
  ArtistName varchar(20), 
  BirthDate date, 
  DeathDate date, 
  ADescription varchar(100), 
  CONSTRAINT ArtistKey PRIMARY KEY (ArtistName)
)
```

Don't repeat the column data type again when you define which column has a key. And using SQL-Server - there is no `text(100)` data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Artist
  (
    ArtistName VARCHAR(20),
    BirthDate DATE,
    DeathDate DATE,
    ADescription varchar(100),
    CONSTRAINT ArtistKey PRIMARY KEY (ArtistName ));
```

Artistname is already defined and primary key is unique and not null and hence we do not need to it specifically.